# Transferring one Integer from one array to another causes invalid array size

Tags: arrays, swift

In my project, I have two arrays of Ints

In pseduocode;

```
var existingOrders:[ExistingOrder] ...
var completedOrders:[CompletedOrder] ..

protocol ValueProtocol {
    var value: Int { get set }
}


class ExistingOrder: ValueProtocol {
 var value: Int = 0
}

class CompletedOrder: ValueProtocol {
  var value: Int = 0
}
```

Yes, I know that functionality is the same; but I'm needing it to be two classes for a reason that is outside the scope of this question.

One function I'm writing I need to transfer one order from Existing Order to Completed.

In my code I loop through all the values I want to transfer, then transfer them

```
for (index, item) in self.completedOrders.enumerated() {
            item.value = Die.roll()
            self.transfer(index: index, destination: .existingOrder)
        }
```

The transfer function moves it from `existingOrder -> completedOrder` and vice versa.

The problem is this:

When it steps through the array shown above it'll pop an object during the transfer; and now the size of the array has changed and is no longer correct.

Visually stepping through it, it looks like this;

ie;

```
// stepping through the for-loop
existingOrders = [3,2]
transfer > index 0 (Integer value of 3) -> completed
existingOrders = [2]
transfer > index 1 .. crash; because the size of the array isn't correct any more.
```

So the for-loop is going through each item it needs to transfer, but because the transfer itself is amending the for-loop it changes the contents of said array and causes a crash.

The reason I use an index is because sometimes I want a specific item within the existing orders to be transferred.

I'm wondering how I can avoid this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your array in reverse order. That way, the earlier indices will still be valid as the later items are removed:

```
for (index, item) in self.completedOrders.enumerated().reversed() {
    item.value = Die.roll()
    self.transfer(index: index, destination: .existingOrder)
}
```

---

Here's an example of how this works with an array of numbers in which we remove the odds ones:

```
var numbers = Array(1...10) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

var odds = [Int]()

for (index, number) in numbers.enumerated().reversed() {
    if number % 2 == 1 {
        odds.insert(number, at: 0)
        numbers.remove(at: index)
    }
}

print(numbers)  // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
print(odds)     // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Cool, I will give it a go -- I'm also thinking I need to refactor my transfer function so that it is accepts generic object ie: `func transferOrder<C1: Any>(order: C1, toDestination: OrderBookEntryType) where C1: EntryProtocol`   but doing an array in inverse would also work

Comment: Reversing it seems to work and I will test it further, i will accept the answer. I will probably end up refactoring my transfer order function to work with a generic order object that follows `EntryProtocol`